# Get width and height from uploaded image or downloaded blob

Tags: typescript, image

I'm trying to get image height and width from an upload input in typescript.

The upload API call will return data **with only an UUID (I don't have the image URL at no point in this)**

I don't care if I get it before being uploaded to AWS or after (I call for AWS and it sends me a blob of the image).

This might be a repost of a very old (14yo) unanswered question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a clientside javascript snippet embedded in html example for you:
you can change createObjectURL parameter as needed.

```
<html>

<body>
  <input type="file" onchange="fnImageUpload(event)">
  <script>
    async function fnImageUpload(event) {
      const input = event.target;
      const file = input.files[0];

      const imgSz = await getimgSz(file);

      console.log(`Image width: ${imgSz.width}px, height: ${imgSz.height}px`);
    }

    async function getimgSz(blob) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const img = new Image();

        img.onload = () => {
          resolve({
            width: img.width,
            height: img.height
          });
        };

        img.onerror = (error) => {
          reject(error);
        };

        img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      });
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```